# Why is my VS Code debugger not working, it just opens launch.json?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow a Pluralsight tutorial.

I have installed C# extension for VS code.

This is what I have got.

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot showing an initial C sharp program file.]

This is different to what the tutorial I am following has:

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot showing a debug breakpoint pausing execution.]

The differences are, if you look at the bottom left corner of the second image, you can see things like .NET Core Launch, csharp with a tick, Program.cs with a tick

I am not sure if this difference means anything but I am pointing it out just in case it helps give some context.

The issue - when I click start debugging, nothing happens as expected.

When I click debugging, I get the following:

[image]

... but no actual debugging happens, making it useless. There are no error messages either

What I SHOULD see is something like the following:

[image]

As you can see the Debug console is not empty, there is a rectangular bar at the top where there is a red square etc.

I hope the images explain the problem. How can I get my software to work like the one in the tutorial instead of only opening launch.json?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using Visual Studio for this? Also, add the link to the tutorial you are mentioning.

Comment: @Matt Well, it's Pluralsight, adding a link that can be viewed only by people that pays for that account won't help many people

Comment: As you can see there are no debugging configurations, so you can't start the debugger. And it'll help those of us that *do* have Pluralsight! Does the course have downloadable resources that include a more useful `launch.json`?